# ListBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf

Why is there error?
I want screen out selected item's content(In this example .Text)

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="Lbox" SelectionChanged="Lbox_SelectionChanged"
         SelectionMode="Extended">
    <TextBlock>AAA</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>BBB</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>CLabel</TextBlock>
</ListBox>
<Button Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
```

Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ListBoxItem item in Lbox.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsSelected)
        {
            TextBlock t = item as TextBlock;  // Error, Can not cast. But why?
            str.Append(t.Text + " ");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Looking at this in a debugger will show you why there is an error.

Comment: @APerson Can not cast 'ListBoxItem' to 'TextBlock'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're receiving the error because a [`ListBoxItem` is not a `TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx). I believe you can access to content of a `ListBoxItem` via the `Content` property.

You've made your ListBox's root elements TextBlocks. So when you iterate through the `Lbox.Items` collection, they are `TextBlocks` and not `ListBoxItems`.

Instead if you change your XAML to:

```
<ListBox Name="Lbox">
    <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Then this code will work:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var str = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (ListBoxItem item in Lbox.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsSelected)
        {
            str.Append( item.Content + " ");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `item.Content` is no string, but the `TextBlock`. `TextBlock t = item.Content as TextBlock; str.Append(t.Text + " ");`

Comment: That will not work as well...try it in vs and you will see the cast error the same!

Comment: I've updated the answer and it now works (and has been tested ;) )

Comment: Anyway Gui_Minor you should work out bindings for listbox itemssource and binding for seleteditems in listbox. work with what's best in WPF ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (TextBlock item in Lbox.Items)
    {


            str.Append(item.Text + " ");

    }
    MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought `.Items` is a collection of `ListBoxItems` ;)